# Possible to Restrict Contact Creation Declaratively (Account Public Read Only)

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I am attempting to restrict Contact creation here are my OWD:

**Sharing:**

Account: `Public Read-Only`

Contact: `Controlled By Parent`

**Profile Access**

Account: `Read`

Contact: `Create,Read,Edit`

Basically I want to allow users to create Contacts while they are assigned to a specific related record (On an Account they DO NOT own), and *restrict this access declaratively when they are no-longer assigned.*

I'm thinking trigger-logic is the only complete solution at this point, or setting Account to Private OWD.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do here. Without testing myself, could you not just create a record-triggered flow on Contact object that would verify these conditions, and if not met, it would delete the contact record that triggered the flow?

I may have misunderstood your issue but that's how I would go about it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks bhann, your on the right track - there needs to be some sort of "validation" - it appears there is no way other then this to prevent users from creating Contacts on Accounts if they have "Create" on Contact and visibility to the Account record in question.